# How to get callback data from particular url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, callback, payment-gateway

I developed a sample IPG SDK in PHP and javascript. Once payment is finished the API is sending callback payment data to a particular URL(notify URL). So I need to get callback data from notifying URL and display the receipt. I keep listening to the URL. But I did not get any data.

Notify URL - https://test.com/demo/payment.php - callback data is coming from this URL

Accessing URL - https://test.com/demo/receipt.php

> receipt.php

```
<head><script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        get_callback_data(1, Date.now());
    });

    const get_callback_data = function(att, init_time) {
        let seconds = (Date.now() - init_time) / 1000;
        if (seconds < 10) {
            fetch("https://test.com/demo/payment.php").then((res) => {
                res.json().then((data) => {
                    console.log('data :');
                    console.log(data);

                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }
    </script></head>
```

I try with this code also

```
$.getJSON("https://test.com/demo/payment.php", function(result) { 
                console.log(result);
            });
```

I am new to javascript. Can anyone help me to get callback data from notifying URL?
Thank you.

Comment: both urls mentioned return 404 errors

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius. Thank you, I added a sample URL. I am unable to add a real URL. because it pointed to LIVE IPG payment. Once we finished live payment the IPG API will send data to the given notify URL. Is there any way to help without sharing an actual URL?

Comment: The above seems to send a single request if less than 10s has elapsed since making the request - is that correct?

Comment: Yes @Professor Abronsius

Comment: And if more than 10s has elapsed then nothing will happen - surely there exists the possibility that authorising payment might take longer and when this (ajax/fetch) request is sent the response has not been returned to your payment.php script? If so perhaps regular polling until a result is returned might work?

Comment: I checked with IPG providers, They said that callback data is sending to notify url within 2 to 2.30 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235611/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-tvs89).